# Solving linear programming problem with given information

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I want to find the optimal solution to a following linear programming problem:
$$8x_1+120x_2+114x_3\to \min$$
$$x_1+7x_2+3x_3\geq 4,$$
$$x_1+5x_2+5x_3\geq 5,$$
$$x_1+3x_2+10x_3\geq 9,$$
$$x_1+2x_2+15x_3\geq11,$$
$$x_1\geq0, \ \ \ x_2\geq 0, \ \ \ x_3\geq0$$
and solution for its dual problem. I already found the dual problem:
$$4y_1+5y_2+9y_3+11y_4\to \max$$
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4\leq 8,$$
$$7y_1+5y_2+3y_3+2y_4\leq 120,$$
$$3y_1+5y_2+10y_3+15y_4\leq 114,$$
$$y_1\geq 0, \ \ \ y_2\geq 0 , \ \ \ y_3\geq 0 , \ \ \ y_4\geq 0.$$
I also know that in the primal problem solution $x^*_1>0, \ x^*_3>0$ for $x^*=(x_1^*,x_2^*,x_3^*)$ and $y_1^*=y_2^*=0$ for $y^*=(y_1^*,y_2^*,y_3^*,y_4^*)$. How should I use that information to find other coordinates in the optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

To use the complementary slackness to solve this LP problem, we first introduce slack variables $x_{s_i}$ and $y_{s_j}$ in each inequality above.

$$8x_1+120x_2+114x_3\to \min$$
\begin{align}
x_1+7x_2+3x_3-x_{s_1} &= 4 \\
x_1+5x_2+5x_3-x_{s_2} &= 5 \\
x_1+3x_2+10x_3-x_{s_3} &= 9 \\
x_1+2x_2+15x_3-x_{s_4} &= 11
\end{align}
$$x_1\geq0, \ \ \ x_2\geq 0, \ \ \ x_3\geq0, \ \ \ x_{s_1}\geq0, \ \ \ x_{s_2}\geq0, \ \ \ x_{s_3}\geq0, \ \ \ x_{s_4}\geq0$$

$$4y_1+5y_2+9y_3+11y_4\to \max$$
\begin{align}
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_{s_1} &= 8 \\
7y_1+5y_2+3y_3+2y_4+y_{s_2} &= 120 \\
3y_1+5y_2+10y_3+15y_4+y_{s_3} &= 114
\end{align}
$$y_1\geq 0, \ \ \ y_2\geq 0 , \ \ \ y_3\geq 0 , \ \ \ y_4\geq 0, \ \ \ y_{s_1}\geq0, \ \ \ y_{s_2}\geq0, \ \ \ y_{s_3}\geq0$$

By complementary slackness of the optimal solution,
\begin{align}
x^*_iy^*_{s_i} &= 0 \,\forall i \in \{1,2,3\} \\
x^*_{s_j}y^*_j &= 0 \,\forall j \in \{1,2,3,4\}
\end{align}

It's given that $x^*_1>0, \ x^*_3>0$, so $y^*_{s_1}=0, \ y^*_{s_3}=0$.  This means that the first and the third inequalities in the dual problem are in fact equalities.  Substituting $y_1^*=y_2^*=0$ into these equalities, we have

\begin{cases}
y^*_3+y^*_4 &= 8 \\
10y^*_3+15y^*_4 &= 114,
\end{cases}

which gives $y^*_3=\frac65,y^*_4=\frac{34}{5}$.  From this, we further deduce that $x^*_{s_3}=0, \ x^*_{s_4}=0$.  Similar to the dual problem, we have a system of simultaneous linear equations.

\begin{cases}
x^*_1+3x^*_2+10x^*_3 &= 9 \\
x^*_1+2x^*_2+15x^*_3 &= 11
\tag{*}\label{sys}
\end{cases}

This is not enough, so we think about the second inequality in the dual problem.  We aim at proving that it's a strict inequality (i.e. $y^*_{s_2} > 0$), so that we can conclude that $x^*_2 = 0$.

\begin{align}
y^*_{s_2}&=120-3y^*_3-2y^*_4\\
&=120-3\cdot\frac65-2\cdot\frac{34}{5}\\
&=\frac{514}{5}\\
&>0
\end{align}

Thus the system \eqref{sys} can be rewritten as

\begin{cases}
x^*_1+10x^*_3 &= 9 \\
x^*_1+15x^*_3 &= 11,
\tag{#}\label{sys1}
\end{cases}

which gives $x^*_1=5, x^*_3=\frac25$ as the solution.

Hence, we have $x^*=(x_1^*,x_2^*,x_3^*)=(5,0,\frac25)$ and $y^*=(y_1^*,y_2^*,y_3^*,y_4^*)=(0,0,\frac65,\frac{34}{5})$ as an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ be the slack variables of the primal, and $f_1,f_2,f_3$ the slack variables of the dual.

By the [complementary slackness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Complementary_slackness) conditions:

- $x_1^*>0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad f_1=0$
- $x_3^*>0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad f_3=0$

And since $y_1^*=y_2^*=0$, it follows that $y_3^*$ and $y_4^*$ satisfy
\begin{cases}
y_3^*+y_4^*=8 \\
10y_3^*+15y_4^*=114
\end{cases}
Solving for $y_3^*$ and $y_4^*$ yields
\begin{cases}
y_3^*= \frac{6}{5} \\
y_4^*= \frac{34}{5}
\end{cases}

Plugging these values in the second constraint, we get
$$
0+0+3\frac{6}{5}+2\frac{34}{5}+f_2=120\quad \Rightarrow \quad f_2 =\frac{514}{5}
$$

Again, by complementary slackness:

- $y_3^*>0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad e_3=0$
- $y_4^*>0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad e_4=0$
- $f_2>0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x_2^*=0$

Therefore $x_1^*$ and $x_3^*$ satisfy

\begin{cases}
x_1^*+0+10x_3^*=9 \\
x_1^*+0+15x_3^*=11
\end{cases}
which gives us
\begin{cases}
x_1^*= 5 \\
x_3^*= \frac{2}{5}
\end{cases}

Plugging these values in the two first constraints, we get $e_1=\frac{11}{5}$, $e_2=2$ and finally $y_1^*=y_2^*=0$ by complementary slackness again.

In summary:
$$
\boxed{
(x_1^*,x_2^*,x_3^*)=(5,0,\frac{2}{5})\quad \mbox{and}\quad (y_1^*,y_2^*,y_3^*,y_4^*)=(0,0,\frac{6}{5},\frac{34}{5})
}$$